# Save related objects when inserting from DynamicData form

Tags: database, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, dynamic-data

I have EF Code First data context, and for some tables (codebooks) dynamic data web application is used for administration. When entity is created through DD interface, everything looks ok, for example when I create a Book, which has property of type Author named Author, I get to choose author by name from dropdown list.

The problem is when saving entity, that property in Book entity is null, and I cannot find a way to at least read Id of selected author in dropdown in codebehind (Insert.aspx.cs). Unfortunately, I don't have Id of Author as property in Book, only whole Author object.

Is there any way to overcome this problem in DynamicData?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to overcome this is to have ID of referenced entity as a property, with

```
[ForeignKey("ReferencedEntityPropertyName")]
public int ReferencedEntityPropertyId {get; set;}
```

attribute, where ReferencedEntityPropertyName is Author in this case.

This way, dynamic data page sets id of referenced object into corresponding property and everything works fine.

This, however, is not the best possible solution in this case as imposes changes to entity models, which is not what I like to do when rest of system is working if there are no real unit tests to verify that this ain't broke something.